# Is the conversion between font formats SFD and TTF lossy?

Tags: fonts, truetype, fontforge

Here are 2 steps I did:

1. I have opened a TTF font file (**212 KiB**) with a Fontforge and saved it as a SFD file (1.5 MiB).
2. Then, without making any changes to the font project I saved it again as a TTF and it resulted in a file of **112 KiB**.

Why might it have changed the size so significantly? Was some crucial information lost?

**UPDATE**. I'm asking this because I want to start developing an improved version of the font (on github for example). Hence, could a TTF be considered as a source file for font? That is, is mere original TTF file enough to start fixing it without losing prior information?

Answer (score 4):

The conversion from TTF -> SFD -> TTF will, in most cases, be lossy, since the TTF format can store much more than Fontforge understands. What is lost will depend on what was in the original TTF, what operations you perform in Fontforge, and settings you apply in Fontforge.

**BUT**: the bigger question is whether the loss matters. That's harder to answer. For example, one thing that can get lost is the TrueType hints (also known as 'instructions'; these are essentially mini-programs stored with the glyph data, that instruct the renderer how to modify the outlines to cause better rendering patterns at certain sizes, under certain conditions, etc.). If the original hints weren't very good, then losing them won't be a big deal.

In any case, it is probably moot because it's unlikely that you'll ever locate SFD source for the font you have. It's quite likely that the font was not even originally developed with Fontforge (there are many other font-creation packages available), so it would be impossible to go back to SFD source.

If your goal is to improve anyway, I would just accept whatever loss comes along with this one-time conversion, and possibly address the losses as part of your improvement process.

Comment: Well, then I have 2 questions:

1) Are there other programs that can import more information than FontForge?
2) The hinting of my font is very good. And I have checked and turns out that hinting instructions were preserved. If it's not hinting instructions, then how can I check what information was lost?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) You will need some type of diff/comparison tool. You might be able to get somewhere with fonttools/ttx.